# Aspect fit programmatically in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgrect, rect, aspect-fit

I want to insert one view into another with aspect fit option. But I can't just set `contentMode` for some reasons.

Could you provide a solution via resizing of the inner `CGRect` according to the outer `CGRect`?

And yes, there are a lot of similar questions but no one provides such solution.

Comment: You can create enum or string in other view and set it in viewdidLoad.Means while going to another controller set tat enum with AspectFit and set tat enum in `viewdidLoad`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### I wrote a function that should achieve what you desire.

It will return the `CGRect` of a given `innerRect`, after scaling it to fit within a given `outerRect`, while maintaining aspect ratio. The `innerRect` will be centered within the `outerRect`.

```
static inline CGRect aspectFitRect(CGRect outerRect, CGRect innerRect) {

    // the width and height ratios of the rects
    CGFloat wRatio = outerRect.size.width/innerRect.size.width;
    CGFloat hRatio = outerRect.size.height/innerRect.size.height;

    // calculate scaling ratio based on the smallest ratio.
    CGFloat ratio = (wRatio < hRatio)? wRatio:hRatio;

    // The x-offset of the inner rect as it gets centered
    CGFloat xOffset = (outerRect.size.width-(innerRect.size.width*ratio))*0.5;

    // The y-offset of the inner rect as it gets centered
    CGFloat yOffset = (outerRect.size.height-(innerRect.size.height*ratio))*0.5;

    // aspect fitted origin and size
    CGPoint innerRectOrigin = {xOffset+outerRect.origin.x, yOffset+outerRect.origin.y};
    CGSize innerRectSize = {innerRect.size.width*ratio, innerRect.size.height*ratio};

    return (CGRect){innerRectOrigin, innerRectSize};
}
```

**You can then use this like so:**

```
// outer rect
CGRect outerRect = CGRectMake(0, 100, self.view.bounds.size.width, 500);

// outer rect's view
UIView* v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:outerRect];
v.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
[self.view addSubview:v];

// inner rect
CGRect innerRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width*2, 500);
CGRect scaledInnerRect = aspectFitRect(v.bounds, innerRect);

// inner rect's view
UIView* v1 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:scaledInnerRect];
v1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[v addSubview:v1];
```

**In this case, the `innerRect` is too wide for the `outerRect`, so it will be scaled according to it's width.**

[image]

**Here, the red area is the `innerRect` and the green area is the `outerRect`.** They both originally had the same height, but after being scaled down (as it was 2x as wide), the `innerRect` now has half the height of the `outerRect`.

Here the `innerRect` is added as a subview to the `outerRect`. **If you want to add them to the same superview, you can pass the `outerRect`'s `frame` into the function, rather than the `bounds`.**

Answer (score 4):

Here are CGSize and CGRect extensions for fitting a size within another size and fitting a rect within another rect respectively:

```
extension CGSize
{
    func sizeThatFitsSize(_ aSize: CGSize) -> CGSize
    {
        let width = min(self.width * aSize.height / self.height, aSize.width)
        return CGSize(width: width, height: self.height * width / self.width)
    }
}

extension CGRect
{
    func rectThatFitsRect(_ aRect:CGRect) -> CGRect
    {
        let sizeThatFits = self.size.sizeThatFitsSize(aRect.size)

        let xPos = (aRect.size.width - sizeThatFits.width) / 2
        let yPos = (aRect.size.height - sizeThatFits.height) / 2

        let ret = CGRect(x: xPos, y: yPos, width: sizeThatFits.width, height: sizeThatFits.height)
        return ret
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Your First View
    UIView *firstView = self;

    // Your second View
    UIView *secondView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero]; change
    newSubview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [containerView addSubview:newSubview];

    // Top Constraint
    [firstView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:secondView
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                 toItem:firstView
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                             multiplier:1.0
                                                               constant:0.0]];
     // Leading Constraint                                                      
    [firstView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:secondView
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                 toItem:firstView
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                             multiplier:1.0
                                                               constant:0.0]];
    // Bottom Constraint
    [firstView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:secondView
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                 toItem:firstView
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                             multiplier:1.0
                                                               constant:0.0]];
    // Trailing Constraint
    [firstView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:secondView
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                 toItem:firstView
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                             multiplier:1.0
                                                               constant:0.0]];

}
```

I think This helps You.

Comment: If you are using CGRect its not automatically adjusting in all sizes of screen , This is the good solution.

Comment: Yes but I need exactly via CGRect as I wrote. I already handle all the resizing events