# How to properly detects taps on UIImageView with AspectFit scale mode

Tags: ios, uiimageview, autolayout, interface-builder

I have a layout as below. Image view inside a view that takes half of view controller (white one). Image view fills container considering some margins on the top and bottom. I have scale mode on the image view set to aspect fit. All this gives me the the exact visual effect I want.

[image]

However I have also tap gesture recognizer installed on the image view, and I want it to detect taps only on the area where actual image is displayed (due to aspect fit it takes only a part of available space). The image itself will be dynamically changed so that I don't know what aspect ratio it's going to have. What would be the easiest way to achieve this?

I guess I would have to get rid of traililnig and leading constraints on the image view, but what next?

Comment: You'll want to [calculate the frame that the image occupies within the image view](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35510271/2976878) and then only respond to taps within that rect.

Comment: Yeah, calculating if the tap is within the area of the image was my first idea. However I counted on some easier solution as this seems to be quite common problem. But if there is no better option...

Answer (score 0):

After set the `UIImage` of `UIImageView` update the `frame` of `UIImageView` as per image.

[How to make UIImageView automatically resize to the size of the image loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12603025/how-to-make-uiimageview-automatically-resize-to-the-size-of-the-image-loaded)

Check above link.

Comment: Is modifying the frame programatically the only option? I thought it could be achieved using auto layout somehow.

Comment: No as per me. Have to set frame of imageview as per the image

Answer (score 0):

First, find the size of image and then update frame of ImageView. Set x and y position according to size of image and requirement.

```
UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"draft"];

CGSize mySize = [img size];

CGRect newFrame=CGRectMake(0, 0, mySize.width, mySize.height);
NSLog(@"height  : %f  width : %f",mySize.height,mySize.width);

myImageView.frame = newFrame;
myImageView.image = img;
```

Comment: Not exactly. This way the image won't fit the container. However it's quite easy to calculate the proper size but I was hoping for avoiding modifying the frame programatically.

Comment: you have to update frame. there is no other option. if you want to keep image in center then use (self.view.frame.size.width/2) - (imageView.frame.size.width/2) as value of x and set y accordingly.

Comment: Ok, thanks. In this case I will rather calculate if the tap is within area of the actual image and leave the trailing and leading margins.

Comment: yeah, you can try that also...!